# Leap Motion : some basic info?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gesture, leap-motion

Note:Only for leap motion users.

I have been using **Leap Motion Device** since two weeks now and the more I use it,the more I want to know about it.
I was wondering whether my laptop can handle multiple leap devices.Is this possible.

This technology is still in its nascent stage and there is not much info available on search engines.

My Questions:

1. can my laptop handle multiple leap devices?
2. Are there any good documentation for development of leap applications?I found it only [here](http://js.leapmotion.com/api/v0.2.0/docs)
3. Any other ***API***'s?
4. I am thinking about using this device not only keeping it on my desk,but at various other positons.For example--Head so that i can view the gestures on a projector.Is it possible with leap device or the range of it is a matter of concern?

I thought of posting this question in stack exchange-programmers,but i think its worth taking the risk.hope it does not get closed.
Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At this time, only one device is recognized per computer. Multiple devices should be supported in the future.
2. There is lots of documentation on the Leap Motion Developer center: https://developer.leapmotion.com/getting_started
3. I'm not sure what you mean by "other APIs," but Leap Motion directly supports C++, C#, Objective-C, Java, Python, and JavaScript. There are a number of other languages and wrappers created by the developer community (including ActionScript). On the page at the link given above, there is a list of these community projects.
4. The Leap Motion device has a range of about 2 feet in each direction (in the shape of an inverted pyramid). Use the "diagnostic visualizer" accessible from the Troubleshooting page of the Leap Motion Control panel to get an interactive visualization of the Leap Motion data -- it should give you a good picture of the device capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

For question number 4, we tried to mount the controller facing to a surface. The controller can't handle it well. The hand (between Leap Motion and the surface) couldn't be recognized by the SDK.

Comment: see: https://forums.leapmotion.com/showthread.php?1005-Technical-specifications&p=5795&viewfull=1#post5795

Answer (score 0):

I guess this [link](https://forums.leapmotion.com/showthread.php?348-Multiple-Leaps-on-single-computer&highlight=multiple%20controllers) would help you out giving clarity for the first question.

Personally, I was able to find the actionscript documentation([link](http://logotype.se/leapmotion/docs/package-summary.html)) very helpful. I was not able to find a good documentation page for java but the methods and classes are pretty much the same for the both.

And regarding the 4th question I concur with otis23. Its not that great in handing other positions.